# Bash Shell Hangs on ?+Tab-complete

Tags: macos, bash, unix, tab-completion

I often use tab completion in Bash when completing directories, but I find that it hangs for an unacceptable amount of time if I accidentally include a question mark in the directory. I'd like to know why and how to prevent it if possible. Here's the scenario:

I start a command and use the <kbd>~</kbd> key to represent home:

```
ls ~?Desktop/co
```

Oops! I held down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> for a split-second too long. I had intended for <kbd>?</kbd> to be <kbd>/</kbd>. But (oh no!) muscle memory has already kicked in. I've hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> before I noticed the mistake. Now I'm stuck waiting for the shell to beep angrily at me. Usually a minute or two.

What happened? Why did the question mark cause it to hang and eventually beep? Any way to stop it from hanging?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. Anything interesting related to shell configuration/customization? Can you reproduce it with a newly created account on your system?

Comment: I tried it out myself and bash responds normally. But keep in mind that `?` usually is the character used to mark one unknown character in a string, so this might causing it.

Comment: How many files are in that directory?

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'm using bash-it (a bash framework). What's strange, though, is I actually just tried it in zsh. It does the same thing. csh beeps immediately. Presumably they're all sourcing different startup files than bash, so I don't know what to say.

Answer (score 1):

Bash may be enumerating all userids that match the pattern `?Desktop` to see if there's a file whose name starts with `co` in their home.  If you have user's with home directories on file servers, that means network traffic, which might be slow if the NFS servers (or NIS) takes time to respond.